# Что по стандарту является переполнением?

Tags: c++

Рассмотрим два фрагмента кода:

Первый:

```
unsigned int y = 0;
y = y - 1;
```

Второй:

```
unsigned long long x = 1ll << 60;
unsigned int y = x;
```

В первом это переполнение. Считается ли переполнением второй вариант? Или это конвертаций `long long` to `int` и пункты стандарта, касающиеся переполнения, тут формально неприменимы?

Comment: Переполнение это установка флага СF

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov: ... а также когда молоко начинает переливаться через край бидона. Какое отношение "флаг CF" имеет к языку С++?

Answer (score 4):

Стандарт языка не определяет формального термина "переполнение". Это - неформальный термин, упоминающийся только в ненормативном тексте стандарта, т.е. в сносках, заметках и примерах.

При этом по определению беззнаковая арифметика следует правилам арифметики по модулю, т.е. считается, что она в принципе не переполняется (кроме, разве что, конвертации плавающих значений в целые). Так что с этой точки зрения ни в вашем первом варианте, ни в вашем втором варианте переполнения нет.

В совсем же неформальной изложении мы может назвать обе ситуации "переполнением". Но, опять же, в беззнаковой арифметике оба варианта ведут себя одинаково, в соответствии с правилами арифметики по модулю.

Comment: А если убрать unsigned? `int x = 1LL<<36;` - это же не UB?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Это не UB, это IDB.

Comment: Но знаковое переполнение - это UB. Значит, раз тут нет UB, то и переполнением такая ситуация не считается.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Знаковое переполнение в арифметических операторах - UB. Знаковое переполнение при преобразовании одного целого типа в другой никогда не было UB, а всегда было именно IDB. Называете ли вы последнюю ситуацию "переполнением", "непомещанием" или еще как - ваше личное дело.